# MySQL WHERE clause construction issue

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I use this to filter records by LocState:
(States are passed as pipe delimited values like shown below but will be a parameter)

```
INSTR(CONCAT('|','TX|OH','|'),e.LocState) > 0
```

But...how can I make it work for something like this?:

```
INSTR(CONCAT('|','AO|WH15','|'),e.ProgramCode) > 0
```

It also causes a match for ProgramCode == 'WH1'.

```
POSITION(e.ProgramCode IN CONCAT('|','AO|WH15','|')) > 0
```

Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have data records like this:

```
ID    ProgramCode
1     WH1
2     WH15
```

And you want to filter records that match `WH1`. If you are using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ProgramCode INSTR(CONCAT('|','AO|WH15','|'),e.ProgramCode) > 0
```

You're essentially saying:

> Select records where ProgramCode is in the following string: `'|A0|WH15|'`

And since `'WH1'` is *in* `'WH15'` you get a false positive.

You would be better off using the `WHERE IN` construct, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ProgramCode IN ('A0', 'WH15');
```

This means:

> Select records where ProgramCode (in its entirety) is in the following set of strings: `'A0', 'WH15'`

If your filter criteria is passed as a pipe-delimited string, you'll need to parse it first so you can set up the proper data set for the `IN` arguments.

You might also be interested in using [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html) since MySQL supports them.